# Setting an return value from Stored procedure on if condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have  an SP  with some  condition like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from bom_steel where fpart = @fpart)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO bom_steel 
            VALUES (@fPart,@fL,@fH,@fW,@fDesc)
        END
    ELSE if(Select * from Employee where Empid = @empid)
        BEGIN
            Return  ‘1’
        END
Else
Begin
UPDATE bom_steel 
            SET fl=@fl, fh=@fH, fW=@fW 
            where Empid =@ empid
end

when this condition passes , I am returning an value  as  1
ELSE if(Select * from Employee where Empid = @empid)
        BEGIN // here i will  to be  doing any operation(DML) .so i want to just return an value as  '1'                
               Return  ‘1’
        END
```

In my  code behind
 Here   cmd is SqlCommand

```
Int intcount= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here in this condition it always retuens an value  as  -1;

Even I am setting an return value as ‘1’it is still returingf an value as  -1

can any one tell me what  should i do in order to return an value  as  1  from there

any help would be  great 
 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
Int intcount= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

instead of

```
Int intcount= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) only returns the number of rows affected.

Also, additionally, remove the single quotes in the return value as Andrew indicated below or change the type of intCount to string instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a character value, not an `int`. Try removing the single quotes.

Also what InSane said; `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected. Though that makes me wonder about your example; why would that return -1?

Comment: @Ardman - It's about time I beat *anyone* to an easy one! I've been getting beaten all morning. hehe!

Comment: I'm interested to know if the "return 1" in the procedure will return that value back to the caller, as BOL states: "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1." Which seems to imply that even a "return" statement would result in a -1 going back to the client.

Comment: @Tony - `return 1` will send that return value, yes. Because a SP could contain multiple statements doing different things, you can return any value you wish that is an `int`; For example, you could sum the rows affected by the multiple statements in the SP. But the problem here seems to be the incorrect value, and also how it is being called.

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks, I thought it should return the value but was confused by the seemingly contradictory message from BOL.

Comment: @Tony - I'm interested to see if this fixes the issue; I suspect there may be something else going on in this case. Then again, maybe the -1 is being returned as 'records affected' because of the fact that 'another operation' is happening last in the SP - `return (char)`

Comment: @Andrew Barber - Whips n' Chains?